# Получить записи из двух связанных таблиц

Tags: yii2

У меня есть две таблицы Host (поля id, ...) и Request (поля id, host_id...) связанные по id=host_id
Мне надо получить записи из таблицы Host со всеми полями и поле count количество записей в таблице Request.
Как правильно можно написать запрос?

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['r.*, count(r.host_id) as count'])
->from('host as h')
->leftJoin('request as r', 'h.id = r.host_id')
->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если память не изменяет - то как-то так...

```php
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(['r.*', new Expression('count(r.host_id) as cnt')])
->from('host as h')
->leftJoin('request as r', 'h.id = r.host_id')
->groupBy(['h.id'])
->all();
```

Comment: не работает, но спасибо за попытку

Comment: в смысле - `не работает`? Приведите текст сообщаемой `Yii2` ошибки.

Comment: ничего не возвращает

Comment: https://klisl.com/yii2-use-count.html 
тут пример приведен но тоже не работает. Понят не могу почему.

Comment: Проверьте есть ли у Вас вообще записи в этих двух таблицах.

Comment: да записи есть в таблицах<br/>

```$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['request.host_id, count(request.id) as count'])
        ->from('request')
        ->rightJoin('host', 'host.id=request.host_id')
        ->where(['>','host.requests_deadline',$date])
        ->orderBy('count DESC')
        ->groupBy('request.host_id')
        ->limit($quantity)
        ->all();```

Comment: так работает, но можно выводить только поля таблицы Request.  host.* не работает

Comment: Почитайте разницу между `leftJoin` и `rightJoin`